# why an integer can be assigned to a string variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, type-conversion, stdstring

In Visual Studio 2013, the compiler will report error if I write:

```
std::string test = 3;
```

showing:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>'.

However, if I change it to:

```
std::string test = "";
test = 3;
```

it just compiles! Of course will end up with tragic error.

Why this can happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because we have the following assignment operator:

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch )
```

[see cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D).

In this case *int* converts to *char*.

This was subject to a [defect report 2372: Assignment from int to std::string](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2372) which was closed as not a defect (NAD). It says:

> The following code works in C++:
>
> ```
> int i = 300;
> std::string threeHundred;
> threeHundred = i;
> ```
>
> "Works" == "Compiles and doesn't have an undefined behavior". But it
>   may not be obvious and in fact misleading what it does. **This
>   assignment converts an int to char and then uses string's assignment
>   from char**. While the assignment from char can be considered a feature,
>   being able to assign from an int looks like a safety gap. Someone may
>   believe C++ works like "dynamically typed" languages and expect a
>   lexical conversion to take place.
>
> Ideally the assignment from char could be deprecated and later
>   removed, but as a less intrusive alternative one could consider adding
>   a SFINAEd deleted function template:
>
> ```
> template <typename IntT> // enable if is_integral<IntT>::value
> basic_string& operator=(IntT) = delete;
> ```

and the resolution was:

> This should be addressed by a paper addressed to LEWG

Comment: I knew this right away [because I tweeted about this recently](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1020967447040425985), the follow on discussion is worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is assignable from `char`. `int` is implicitly convertible to char.